# Apply a Channel N times from an initial value

Tags: scalaz, scalaz-stream

I have a function `f` and a channel `c`

```scala
def f(i: Int) = Task.now(i + 1)

val c = channel.lift(f)
```

I would like to continuously apply the function `f` an arbitrary number of times (or indefinitely) to the output of the previous computation. I'm providing the initial value.

I can define a process `p`

```scala
val p = Process.emit(1).through(c)
```

but this only gets executed once.

How can I keep applying `c` to the output of the last computation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the `iterateEval[F[_], A](start: A)(f: A => F[A])` function to do that

```scala
val p = Process.iterateEval(1)(f).take(10)
```